# How to map an input validation error to a specific error code in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, exception

I am having a case in which I would like to do some input validation on the @RequestParams of an endpoint.

I know about Validators and Custom Validators, and my current strategy implies creating a wrapper object around the RequestParams, a custom validator and apply class level the annotation that triggers the custom validation.

My problem is that the custom validation is implementing ConstraintValidator, which means that the validator will either return true or false, and an error will be created by Spring with some text (I also know that I can change this text). My desire, however, is to create a custom payload back to the client. An example could be

```
class MyError {
   int code;
   String message;
}
```

The way to return this object is through a @ControllerAdvice Error handler, which understands that a ConstraintValidationException should return my custom payload format. However, I need to return different codes and messages for different reasons on the input validation failed. For example:

- A Field is empty -> code XXX
- A Field is formatted incorrectly -> code YYY

As far as I know, there is little customization possible on the exception that is reachable from my @ControllerAdvice, I can get a list of errors that happened but I cannot easily determine what happened. (Technically I can, but it would have to be based on the message string, which is pretty weak).

Is there a way to provide extra data to the Exception so I can distinguish from the @ControllerAdvice what happened and create my custom error response accordingly?

Am I approaching it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the `BindException` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindException.html) with the `@ExceptionHandler`. This contains detailed information about all validation errors. For example, with `e.getFieldErrors()` you can access all errors associated with fields.

For example, for a field

```
@MyConstraint
@Length(min = 3)
private String field;
```

that failed validation you get the following information in the exception:

- Field error in object `data` on field `field`: rejected value [XY]; codes [Length.data.field,Length.field,Length.java.lang.String,Length].
- Field error in object `data` on field `field`: rejected value [XY]; codes [MyConstraint.data.field,MyConstraint.field,MyConstraint.java.lang.String,MyConstraint].

From this you can see that it failed the `@Length` constraint and the custom `@MyConstraint` constraint.